# Displaying Live Webcam Feed in OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

Many other people have had this problem, but their solutions do not work for me. I am attempting to display a live webcam feed using OpenCV with the following script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (cap.isOpended()):
     ret,img = cap.read()
     cv2.imshow("input",img)
     k = cv2.waitKey(10)
     if k == 27:
          break
```

This is just as it was given on the OpenCV website, but I only get a near black screen. Several red, green, and blue pixels show up randomly (as can be seen in the image below). [image: Output Example]

I know my webcam works because I have tested it, so that cannot be the problem. Some people suggest not running the script in IDLE, changing the index in VideoCapture(), and printing the array of the image to test if there is data there. I still get the same results if I run it from the Command Prompt, I changed the index to several different numbers (including -1), and printing the array to test for data and it only displays the stray pixel values (and nothing else).

Any help is always appreciated with this matter.

P.S. Running Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: you have identation error in the `while` loop , and u should add `cap.release();cv2.destroyAllWindows()` before break

Comment: It seems that your windows might not have the driver for your camera. Check if you can access the live feed on a media player application like vlc.